# How to use a local file as crate logo when generating rustdoc?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc, cargo-doc

It is possible to set both the *favicon* and the *logo* of the rustdoc for a crate by using:

- `#![doc(html_favicon_url = "<url_to>/favicon.ico")]`
- `#![doc(html_logo_url = "<url_to>/logo.png")]`

as documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/the-doc-attribute.html).

However I do not want to upload my logo publicly and would therefore like to automatically include these files in `/target/doc` and reference them from there.

Currently I have put the respective data urls (base64 encoded) into these fields and it works fine, but it enormously bloats the source file where these attributes are set.

I know I could just copy the images into `target/doc` after generating the documentation using a script and then reference them using the relative url, but I would like to avoid this, so that I can still generate the documentation using `cargo doc`.

#### Edit

The suggestion from the comment to set the `--output` flag of `rustdoc` using [`rustdocflags`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustdocflags) in `.cargo/config.toml` also did not work, because it leads to `error: Option 'output' given more than once`. Apart from that, it is not suited for me, because (at least as far as I understand) I can only give absolute paths there, whereas I would need a solution using relative paths for the images, because I have those images stored in a subdirectory of the cargo root directory, to allow for easy transfer to another system using git, etc.

Comment: "*but I would like to avoid this, so that I can still generate the documentation using `cargo doc`*"—perhaps you could elaborate on this a little more?  Would a script, or `cargo` command, that wraps both actions together not suffice?

Comment: If I put both actions in a script I will have to run the script (e.g. ./myscript.sh) which I think is not ideal, because then I will have to remember that for this particular project I can not generate the documentation using `cargo doc` as usual.

Comment: You could create a script that forwards its arguments to `rustdoc` and then copies the desired static assets into the resulting output folder; and then configure Cargo to use that script via the [`build.rustdoc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustdoc) setting within `.cargo/config.toml` inside your project root.

Comment: @eggyal The `build.rustdoc` sounds interesting. I tried to supply my bash script, but it seems only executables are allowed (at least on windows), because I now get the error `%1 is not a valid Win32 application. (os error 193)`. I might create a small executable to do this, but I am not sure it is worth the hassle, because then I can also just keep the base64 encoded images (especially considering, that I would need to add the executable to git, too)...

Comment: I think you should be able to resolve that error for a script, but I'm not familiar enough with Windows.  Perhaps try opening another question about that?

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose you could set [`build.rustdocflags`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustdocflags) to set [`--output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/command-line-arguments.html#-o--output-output-path) to an existing folder that contains your image?

Comment: To be clear, the idea was to output the generated rustdoc to a location that already contained the image in order that a relative path to the image would succeed.  Anyway, I'm now thinking that a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) that copies the image into the target directory may actually be your best option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the latest comment from *eggyal* I finally figured out how to do this:

In my `build.rs` I copy the files to `target/doc/`:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Copy the images to the output when generating documentation
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=assets/doc");
    std::fs::copy("assets/doc/logo.ico", "target/doc/logo.ico").expect("Failed to copy crate favicon when building documentation.");
    std::fs::copy("assets/doc/logo.png", "target/doc/logo.png").expect("Failed to copy crate logo when building documentation.");
}
```

and then I just had to make sure, to use an absolute path when referencing them, like so:

```rust
#![doc(html_favicon_url = "/logo.ico")]
#![doc(html_logo_url = "/logo.png")]
```

In general it would be better to read the [`CARGO_TARGET_DIR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) environment variable instead of hardcoding `target/doc`, but this is [not yet available](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/7325) in build scripts.

Comment: You might want to use env(OUT_DIR) instead of hard-coding “target/doc”.

Comment: Also, I don’t think your `rerun-if-changed` is correct.  target/doc is only changed by the build, *after* the build script has run.  You should instead point it at your assets directory, so the build script is re-run and re-copies images to the output directory if *they* have changed.

Comment: Well, but then they wouldn’t be copied after cargo clean, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Everything gets rerun after cargo clean.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you